# GraphQL query with multiple ids using Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, graphql-tag

I have a query that takes an array of ids as parameter. In the array, I can add or remove ids based on the selected documents.

**The problem is that it does not launch the query every time the array of id changes** but I don't understand why.

I've also tried changing the query `options.fetchPolicy` with `network-only` and `no-cache` but it doesn't work.

This is my query:

```
const GET_DATA = gql`
    query docs($selectedDocs: [ID]) { 
        docs(selectedDocs: $selectedDocs) {
            _id
            name
            description
        }
    }
`;
```

And this is the render function of the component:

```
render() {
        const { selectedDocs } = this.props;
        console.log(selectedDocs)
        return (
            <Query
                query={GET_DATA}
                variables={{ selectedDocs }}
                fetchPolicy="network-only"
                // fetchPolicy="no-cache"
                notifyOnNetworkStatusChange
            >
                {({ loading, error, data, refetch, networkStatus }) => {
                    if (loading) return "Loading...";
                    if (error) return "Error!";

                    console.log(data);
                    return (
                        <div>
                            docs list
                        </div>
                    )
                }}
            </Query>
        );
    }
```

This is the parent component render method:

```
render() {
    const { selectedDocs } = this.state;
    return (
        <Docs
            selectedDocs={selectedDocs}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rendering of your parent component and how the `selectedDocs` are passed

Comment: I pass the `selectedDocs` as props. I updated the question

Comment: Does `console.log(selectedDocs)` fire every time you change the prop?

Comment: Yes and it has the correct content!

Comment: @Stefano that's good, so then do you see network request in Network panel of DevTools every time you change the prop? (fetchPolicy must stay "network-only")

Comment: No, the problem is that I don't see the request in Network panel every time I change the prop

Comment: Do you see doc list after the first query? or maybe that query hangs with any error?

Comment: Yes the first time it runs the query exactly. And also other times that changes the prop it runs the query but not every time.

Comment: Sorry, my ideas are over. Not sure what the problem can be... If only the client is some way misconfigured. Never had the problem like yours.